# How to create 3d text in MFC[CFormView]

Tags: c++, mfc

Now i'm try to search google but can't find how to create 3d text.I see it maybe use library such as OpenGL or freetype-gl,however it not say so much espicially step by step >.<.Thank for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_11__15/28001/

The Demo named "outline fonts" maybe that's what you want,it has source code for windows.

you mentioned you want to draw it in CFormView,the source code above using it's own window that created by hand.

you just have to remove that part of the code,then pass CFormView's hwnd to the code that create opengl context, everything should work the same.

the source code defined this:

```
HWND        hWnd=NULL; //used by demo's window,


if (!(hDC=GetDC(hWnd))) /change hWnd to "yourCFormViewPointer"->m_hWnd
```

Also you might not want to use that loop from the source code,put the loop code inside CFormView::ondraw to check if code works until you implement 'real loop'

Comment: thank for your help.But it't code is so hard to understand.In my main form i dont know which toolbox is add to show 3d text.